# How do I create an NSFont that is both Bold and Italic?

Tags: cocoa, fonts

This is a beginner's question about font handling in Cocoa. I have a font family, e.g. *Verdana*, that has the following typefaces: *Regular*, *Bold*, *Italic*, and *Bold Italic*. I know those typefaces exist since they are available in the Fonts panel.

This works:

```
NSFont *regular = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:75];
NSFont *bold = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:75];
NSFont *italic = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Italic" size:75];
```

This does not work:

```
NSFont *boldItalic = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold Italic" size:75];
```

What is the simplest way to get the *Bold Italic* version of a given font family?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This works:

```
NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
NSFont *boldItalic = [fontManager fontWithFamily:@"Verdana"
                                          traits:NSBoldFontMask|NSItalicFontMask
                                          weight:0
                                            size:75];
```

Comment: I apologize for the obvious plug but I wanted to mention that I've made the [CocoaPuffs](http://github.com/macpgrog-guy/CocoaPuffs) framework available on GitHub and it contains a nice category for working with NSFont and NSFontManager. There are also some details [here](http://macprog.com/simplifying-nsfont/). In this specific case, if you already had a reference to the Verdana font you all you would have needed to do is verdana.fontVariationBoldItalic.

Comment: @aLevelOfIndirection : the two links you gave us are broken.

Comment: Apologies. I've since taken down the framework. I've added a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/macprog-guy/156d33bfefef570a7efb)  just now with the code for it. So go ahead and download it.

Comment: In addition, if you want 'regular weight', `weight` should be `5`, here more details: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfontmanager/1462332-font

Answer (score 10):

See NSFontManager and -convertFont:toHaveTrait:

For more detailed information, I would suggest reading the [Font Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/FontHandling/FontHandling.html) and specifically the section titled [Converting Fonts Manually](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/FontHandling/FontHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH5-SW12).

Note, that the font you are using needs to have some version of it with the traits you are asking for, otherwise, you will get back a font, but without the requested trait.

If, eventually, you are seeking to add an italic trait to a font that doesn't have one, check out:

[How do I get Lucida Grande italic into my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724647/how-do-i-get-lucida-grande-italic-into-my-application)

Answer (score 7):

`Verdana-BoldItalic`.

(The actual name of the bold-italic variant of the font depends on the family, and some font doesn't have bold-italic, Use a `NSFontDescriptor` with `-fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:` to get the exact bold italic font.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Swift** instead:

```swift
let font: NSFont? = NSFontManager.shared.font(
  withFamily: "Verdana",
  traits: [.boldFontMask, .italicFontMask],
  weight: 5,
  size: 12
)
```